# Pass Image to Python3 AWS Lambda via API Gateway

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to upload an image to AWS lambda via API gateway. How do I get the image from the lambda handler?

Local code:

```py
import requests
url = 'https://_________.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/_________'
files = {'image': open('image.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.content)
```

Lambda code:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    image = event['image']??????????????<---HOW DO I GET THE IMAGE?????????????????
```

Note: I do not want to upload the image to S3 then get the image from S3 from the lambda

Comment: what would you like to do with the image in the lambda function?